# Is there a way to select screen sharing options while running headless tests in webdriverio?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests, webdriver-io, selenium-edgedriver

It seems that I cannot auto-select a screen sharing source when running the test in headless mode.

I managed to auto-select a tab using this ChromeDriver argument --auto-select-tab-capture-source-by-title=Example Domain, and it works. However, when I run the test headlessly, it doesn't, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently and was able to make it work by using the `headless=new` argument for ChromeDriver.

From Selenium's [web site](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/):

```
The traditional --headless, and since version 96, Chrome has a new headless mode that allows users to get the full browser functionality (even run extensions). Between versions 96 to 108 it was --headless=chrome, after version 109 --headless=new.

Using --headless=new should bring a better experience when using headless with Selenium.
```